Owner missing privs to route container registry to artifact registry
I'm trying to change the Route from the GCP Container registry to the Artifact registry. I was able to do this without issue in my Dev Google project. I switched to the prod project and I'm getting the following message about missing privs? As owner, I should have access to everything correct?
It mentions something about a "Deny" policy, but there are no deny policies setup.
What do I need to do in order to get this route updated to use artifact registry?

I've also added the storage admin and artifact registry admin roles to my account.. It's still not working.


One way to do this is too lookup the permissions, find the roles and then add those to your credentials (orange redacted). Find the permissions on the list of Google IAM roles, under Artifact Registry roles artifactregistry.projectsettings.* is part of roles/artifactregistry.admin and storage.buckets.update is part of 18 predefined roles but you can find storage.buckets.* is part of roles/storage.admin. Try to use the least powerful roles.

I've added both storage admin role and artifact registry admin role and It's still not working. I should note, for my same account in my dev project, the roles listed are "owner" and "Storage admin" and it worked fine. This seems to be a bug? What else can I do?

owner includes the world and I think storage.admin would be redundant with it. Please update the question with the (revised) error.

I ran into this issue and found the answer here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249369883
basically owner is missing some of the permissions (surprisingly) but if you provide artifact registry repository admin that should cover the missing ones
